# Logstash protobuf for cisco devices

Tags: protocol-buffers, telemetry

I need to Decode the binary data of cisco devices(Using GPB-KV for encoding).
I am using below proto file and generated the ruby file and using in logstash application but not working.

Can anyone please help us to solve this issue.

Proto file:https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/bigmuddy-network-telemetry-proto/blob/final/proto_archive/telemetry.proto

[LogstashCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUv89.png)

Comment: You need to provide the data you are trying to decode, and more details on the error you are getting.

Comment: Couldn't decode protobuf: #<RuntimeError: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).>.  I am getting this exception but partially some data is decoding.